# Twisted TV Titles

Tags: wordplay, visual, knowledge

> This is a puzzle I created for a road rally / puzzle hunt a few years ago.  It shouldn't be very difficult but hopefully will be a bit of fun.  This is my first puzzle, so I welcome any feedback in the comments.

**TWISTED TV**

The creators of this season’s new television shows have clearly run out of ideas.  In fact, each of the new shows pictured or described below is a copy of an existing program with the name changed by a single letter.  The original shows were popular on American television and may have aired anytime from 1950 to today.  Identify the twisted show title and the original.

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Laughing so hard

Comment: I'm very glad you enjoyed it!  I knew it wouldn't last long (solved in about 20 minutes), but I hope you had some fun.

Comment: This was really fun.  I also like the presentation - the visual aspect is great, the colors and cartoons were super enticing :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Team Answer**

1

> "Twin *Peaks*" => "Twin *Beaks*", because of the double-beaks.

2

> "*How* To Get Away With Murder" => "*Cow* To Get Away With Murder", because it is about a cow.

3

> "The Walking *Dead*" => "The Walking *Head*". Found by [ttotherat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9102/ttotherat).

4

> "Glee" => "Glue". Found by [puzzledPig](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38170/puzzledpig) .

5

> "*Dukes* of Hazzard" => "*Nukes* of Hazzard", because it is "Dukes of Hazzard" with atomic weapons(nukes).

6

> "60 *Minutes*" = "60 *Minuses*". Found by [ttotherat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9102/ttotherat).

7

> "*House* M.D." => "*Horse* M.D.". Found by [ttotherat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9102/ttotherat) Or, alternatively, "*Mr.* Ed" => "Dr. Ed". Found by [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio).

8

> "The Big *Bang* Theory" => "The Big *Band* Theory". Found by [puzzledPig](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38170/puzzledpig).

9

> "Mad *Men*" => "Mad *Hen*", because of the angry hen.

10

> "I *Love* Lucy" => "I *Move* Lucy", because it is "I Love Lucy" with relocating.

11

> "Bones" => "Boxes" . Found by [ttotherat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9102/ttotherat).

12

> "Two Broke *Girls*" => "Two Broke *Gills*" because the fish is having trouble breathing air (obviously).

Comment: 7 could also be -> $\color{white}{\text{Dr. Ed}}$<-?  (select to show spoilers)

Comment: Since it's a team effort, you'll probably want to select the "community wiki" checkbox on the edit page.

Comment: (When your own contribution is a considerable part of an answer, as here, I don't think there's any need to CW it.  QuantumTwinkie appears to have answered 6 of 12 without outside help, and acknowledged the other 6 as coming from their respective solvers; I think making this a CW answer and foregoing the rep benefit of the effort in solving those 6 would be noble, but actually unfair to QuantumTwinkie.)

Comment: House, MD was my intended answer, but good alternate with Dr. Ed.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Hope you don't mind the edit.  Was just fixing the spelling of Hazzard and had to do more changes so I figured I'd clean up the formatting some

Comment: @Rubio, how did you do that? the comment box won't take HTML for me (and Markdown has no colors).

Comment: @NH. That's MathJax markdown, which does have colors.  That text is written in white.

Answer (score 10):

Another partial answer:

3:

> *The Walking Head*, playing off *The Walking Dead*

6:

> *60 Minuses*, playing off *60 Minutes*

7:

> *Horse, M.D.*, playing off *House, M.D.*

11:

> *Boxes*, playing off *Bones*

Answer (score 9):

Is 4:

> Glue?  (original: Glee; if you add in a love of paste it would become "glue")

Is 8:

> The Big Band Theory?  (original: The Big Bang Theory; Glenn Miller is associated with big band music)