# Twisted TV Titles, season 2

Tags: wordplay, visual, knowledge

Inspired by [this puzzle by Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61535/twisted-tv-titles), here is a second set of Twisted TV Titles.

Each of the new shows pictured or described below is a copy of an existing program with the name changed by a single letter. The original shows were popular on American television and may have aired anytime from 1950 to today. Identify the twisted show title and the original.

[image: Twelve Twisted TV Titles]

Hint for #11:

> Aired primarily during the 1960s

Comment: Thanks for the link to my original puzzle.  It's great that this is continuing!

Comment: @Pugmonkey - I forsee many good things in the future for your puzzle type!  It's lots of fun!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't claim any originality.  I didn't consciously copy another puzzle, but I grew up reading GAMES magazine, and this seems like something that might have shown up there.  I'm sure its been done before.

Comment: I've seen similar quizzes on for example [Sporcle](https://www.sporcle.com/games/kittypoo/tv-shows-change-a-letter) but this one was much better. Most of the answers were really hard to get but obvious when revealed.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: @Rubio I was still waiting to see if someone would come up with my intended answer for #11. Not sure if [SeanC's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61648/21402) quite fits the clue, although it comes very, very close. Should I accept the community wiki compilation answer as "close enough"?

Comment: @DLosc How about a hint for #11?  Also did you see theonetruepath's new guess at #11?

Comment: @JS1 Hint added, and commented as to why theonetruepath's answer doesn't fit the clue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) ([theonetrupath](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61613/45849))

> NYPD **C**lue -> NYPD **B**lue

2) ([Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61631/45849))

> New**m**art -> New**h**art

3) ([Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61631/45849))

> The **P**unsters -> The **M**unsters

4) ([Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61616/45849))

> Saturday Night **H**ive -> Saturday Night **L**ive

5) ([L_Church](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61635/45849))

> An**t**maniacs -> An**i**maniacs

6) ([theonetrupath](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61613/45849))

> America's Funniest Ho**p**e/**N**ome Videos ->America's Funniest Ho**m**e/**H**ome Videos (Both fit though probably Nome)

7) ([theonetrupath](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61613/45849))

> L**u**st -> L**o**st

8) ([totallyhuman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61634/45849))

> B**o**tman -> B**a**tman

9) ([Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61631/45849))

> The Magic School Bu**g** -> The Magic School Bu**s**

10) ([Peregrine Lennert](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61612/twisted-tv-titles-season-2#comment188035_61641) built off answer by [jaxad0127](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61641/45849))

> Breaking Ba**e** -> Breaking Ba**d**

11) ([Rupert Morrish](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62908/21402))

> **D**ewitched -> **B**ewitched

12) ([Jaap Scherphuis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61648/45849))

> The Daily Sho**e** -> The Daily Sho**w**

Comment: Welp, didn't see BruceWayne's answer, but yeah

Comment: Major credit goes to BruceWayne

Comment: Depending on which is the exact one for #'s 2 & 10, it will be changed

Answer (score 24):

8)

> B**o**tman, playing on B**a**tman.

I thought I should answer this one, considering it's my avatar. :P

Comment: Is the avatar you (and OP) used from a show or something? Or did OP happen to find your avatar, and use it? (also, nice answer!)

Comment: @BruceWayne This is an image that I made myself, and use as an avatar most everywhere. [DLosc asked if they could use it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43292196#43292196) and [I let them](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=43293464#43293464).

Answer (score 18):

12)

> The Daily Shoe (The Daily Show)

Answer (score 16):

2) big guess:

> "Newmart", twisted from "Newhart".  I don't see any other way to make the Vermont connection ...

3)

> "The Punsters", twisted from "The Munsters"

9)

> "The Magic School Bug", twisted from "The Magic School Bus"

Comment: Seems reasonable enough! Now get 9 and 11!

Comment: He's going for it folks :D

Comment: Dang... I just got #9 too.

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to go all out here... first answer go easy

5)

> Antmaniacs (Animaniacs) (They look pretty manic to me...)

Answer (score 14):

I'll kick it off...

1:

> NYPD Clue (NYPD Blue)

6:

> America's Funniest Hope Videos ('Home')

7:

> Lust (Lost)

Another guess at this one:
11:

> The Hood Wife ('Good')

Comment: I think 6 is should be ".... Nome Videos".  "Hope" would work better for Arkansas rather than Alaska.

Comment: 7 is actually fairly accurate as just the original show's title...

Comment: #11 isn't the intended answer and doesn't fit the clue too well, since rot13(ubbq) is pretty much the opposite of "suburban"...

Answer (score 13):

4 is probably

> Saturday Night Hive

Comment: ah, yes, it wasn't stated whose sabbath.

Answer (score 10):

11)

> Charged (from Charmed)

(30 chars required)

Comment: Nice! We're done now someone group them up like the previous thread I dont have time :D

Comment: Huh! This was not my intended answer, but it fits surprisingly well. One possible nitpick: does *Charmed* take place in the suburbs? Wikipedia says it's set in San Francisco.

Answer (score 7):

10)

> Breaking Bab or Bae or Bay (Breaking Bad)
>  (Bae from Peregrine Lennert)

Comment: probably preferable since we don't want to call girls bags...? lol

Comment: @L_Church PL457's answer is based on "spill the beans" instead of girlfriend (which mine is).

Comment: oh... whoops! whistle whistle

Comment: (SPOILER) bae maybe? (covering up most of the name)

Comment: And that explains why I had so much trouble with this one - I'm way too old to call anyone "Bae" ...  But great answer!

Answer (score 6):

10) (far fetched)

> Breaking Bag. / Breaking bad (It contains drugdealers and a broken bag is literally Spilling beans)

Answer (score 3):

Is #11

> Dewitched (not a word, AFAIK, though I learned many interesting facts about dew itch while googling it) -> Bewitched

?

> Because Bewitched has a suburban setting and aired primarily in the 1960s (1964 - 1972).

Comment: Yay! That's what I was looking for. (The titles don't have to be words per se--see also #2, #5, and #8.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a few alternative answers:

2):

> Superstowe -> Superstore + Stowe Vermont

6)

> America's Funniest Nome Videos -> America's Funniest Home Videos but in Nome, Alaska

8)

> Sister Robot -> Mister Robot, but this time about Darlene

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Hope you stay!

Answer (score -3):

8)

> eye-robot(i-robot) evil society

Comment: Are you sure you understood the question? Only one letter should be changed in the title of an existing tv show.