# TV Title Mondegreens

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

Inspired by the [original Twisted TV Titles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61535/twisted-tv-titles) and its [follow-up](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61612/twisted-tv-titles-season-2/), I came up with a similar puzzle. This one builds on the idea of [Mondegreens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) - misheard lyrics (like “Excuse me while I kiss this guy” instead of “Excuse me while I kiss the sky”). This is misheard TV Show Titles.

I’ll give a description of what the show could be, and you can give the misheard title, along with the real show title. For example:

**Clue:** Linda never realized how much she relied on her android until she lost it

**Answer:** Missed Her Robot - Real title: Mister Robot

## Clues

1. A story about herbed black tea - **Clue**: This one is way simpler than you think. If you just name a black tea, you'll likely get it right!
2. The creator of X-Files and Breaking Bad opens an optometry clinic
3. Briefly looking at clones
4. From *The Darjeeling Limited* to *Rushmore*, we learn all
   about this director’s universe
5. Due to the bartender - **Clue**: This refers to a well-known bartender on a show that is currently airing (as of March, 2018) - **Clue 2**: It refers to a very animated bartender
6. Will definitely stay closed without a key
7. Broken Buildings
8. Wander around
9. A man who never drives during the day

Comment: About that "Excuse me while I..." line: I was pretty sure Jimi Hendrix played with words on that line intentionally after the original release. Not sure if it counts as misheard if it is kind of intentional.

Comment: Due to the bartender = Bar tab? Thinking too much I guess :D

Comment: @Ian irrelevant, as we know what the op is talking about

Comment: @TrojanByAccident It was literally just a comment.

Comment: Well known animated bartender - could be "Moe" in the "The Simpsons", I know nothing about airing dates when shows air wherever user1118321 lives.  could be "Howard" in "Family Guy" - but less well known.

Comment: Sorry - could have been more clear about air dates. I'm in the US.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Answers so far:***

1) **A story about herbed black tea**

> The Chai => The Chi [BruceWayne](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15973/brucewayne)

2) **The creator of X-Files and Breaking Bad opens an optometry clinic**

> Vince Gilligan opens an optometry clinic => Gilligan's Eye Land => *Gilligan's Island* - [PuzzledPig](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38170/puzzledpig)

3) **Briefly looking at clones**

> Twin peeks => *Twin Peaks* - [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)

4) **From *The Darjeeling Limited* to *Rushmore*, we learn all about this director’s universe**

> Wes Anderson's universe => Wes' world => *Westworld* - [Somebody](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9309/somebody)

5) **Due to the bartender**

> `Cuz Mo => Cosmos - [Cgz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9676/cgz)

6) **Will definitely stay closed without a key**

> Sure-locked => *Sherlock* - [Xenocacia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30254/xenocacia)

7) **Broken Buildings**

> Faulty towers => *Fawlty Towers* - [Kobi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/46398/kobi)

8) **Wander around**

> Roam => *Rome* - [PuzzledPig](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38170/puzzledpig)

9) **A man who never drives during the day**

> Night rider => *Knight Rider* - [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)

Comment: I thought of that for 9 but "rider" doesn't really fit IMO

Comment: ditto @somebody, rider != drives

Comment: Could 5 be something about a barrister (misheard as barista)?

Comment: But that #1 isn't a TV show.

Comment: #1 is incorrect. Regarding rider vs. driver - I guess you're right. Although we often say people are "riding" motorcycles when they're also driving them. I'll try to be more careful next time.

Answer (score 6):

2:

> Gilligan's Eye Land (Vince Gilligan opens an optometry clinic) -> Gilligan's Island

4 (perhaps a bit of a stretch on my part):

> Anderson's Life (Wes Anderson's universe) -> [Anderson Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_Live)

8:

> Roam -> Rome

Comment: Hmm, 4 could be Westworld

Comment: @somebody that's more likely than mine, isn't it... :)

Comment: @user1118321 is somebody's answer for #4 correct?

Comment: Yes it is! Feel free to add it to the list, or to post it as a separate answer.

Comment: Vince Gilligan didn't create the X-Files though, Chris Carter did. Gilligan was just a writer.

Comment: Oh well. Guess I messed up on that one. Sorry!

Answer (score 6):

A few more...

**3. Briefly looking at clones**

> Twin peeks => Twin Peaks

**9. A man who never drives during the day**

> Night rider => Knight Rider

Answer (score 5):

Please feel free to add to any community answer:

**6: Will definitely stay closed without a key**

> Sherlock (Sure-locked)

Comment: Just beat me to it :)

Answer (score 5):

7. Broken Buildings:

> Faulty towers → Fawlty Towers

Answer (score 3):

1. A story about herbed black tea

> [Rize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rize_tea) -> [Rise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rise_(TV_series))

5. Due to the bartender

> Loose change -> Luke Cage

Answer (score 2):

Would 1. **A story about herbed black tea**, be

> Fifty shades Earl grey (Fifty Shades Of Grey)

Comment: Good idea, but the question specifies TV Shows, rather than books/movies, so I think there is another answer.

Comment: Indeed there is! It's a newer show, if that helps.

Comment: I was thinking about a playing off "A Handmaid's Tale" but I can't think of any teas that could be confused for "Handmaid's" ...

Comment: @Pugmonkey maybe "A handmade tea"

Answer (score 2):

Attempt 2!

1) A story about herbed black tea

> Chai (Tea) -- [The Chi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chi)

Comment: Yes! That's the one!

Comment: @user1118321 - Aha! Good one!

Answer (score 2):

From the most recent hint...
5) Due to the bartender

> Cause Moe (bartender on The Simpsons) =  Cosmos ?

Comment: Yes! That's it! Very well done!

Answer (score 0):

1) A story about herbed black tea

> (Earl) Grey's analogy - Grey's Anatomy

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please remember to post an explanation along with your answer. Hope you stay!

Comment: Nope. Not related to Earl Grey at all.