# Video-games Mondegreens

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, video-games

Inspired by [TV Title Mondegreens](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61761/tv-title-mondegreens?noredirect=1&lq=1), I, too, came up with a similar puzzle. It is still based on [Mondegreens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen), obviously, but with video-games!

Each of these 10 descriptions will lead you to a (weird) phrase or sequence of words wich, when (badly) misheard, will give you the name of the game.

**As an example :**
*An insolent boxing Apollo*
would give:
*A sassy Creed* -> *Assassin's creed*

### And here are the ten clues to find out:

1. Chubbier, next not heavy *(found by [@Saeïdryl](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43050/sae%C3%AFdryl))*
2. Goku's friend wheat powder *(found by [@Saeïdryl](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43050/sae%C3%AFdryl))*
3. Legolas' dishonesty *(found by [@Paige Meinke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38344/paige-meinke))*
4. The Iron man's father balloon for showing-off *(found by [@gnovice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43477/gnovice))*
5. Hot beverage for Spartacus' fellows *(found by [@gnovice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43477/gnovice))*
6. Higher cute marsupial *(found by [@gnovice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43477/gnovice))*
7. Mixed great geographic feature *(found by [@Milo P](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/414/milo-p))*
8. The 18th Ulysses, the 6th, the 15th and the greek 19th *(found by [@Gustavo Gabriel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/44445/gustavo-gabriel))*
9. Assault a person *(found by [@gnovice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43477/gnovice))*
10. Evening meal animal flesh in hot water *(found by [@gnovice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43477/gnovice))*

---

Some may be easy, and some may be far-fetched. Let's see how much you get!

Comment: 11. A forest dog with a blood mark

Comment: @Saeïdryl Wolf-stain ?

Comment: @Saeïdryl Wolven stain -> Wolfenstein ?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it while "reverse-thinking" your descriptions

Comment: It would probably be rude to condense everyone's partial answer into one answer..

Comment: After 1 hour, seven of these have already been found ! The 4, 5 & 7 are still missing

Comment: @A.B. More often that not, resolving a puzzle is a group effort, the check mark will be awarded to the one making the effort to condense all the answers while participating in their elaboration ;)

Comment: @Keelhaul Is it possible to condense them all into a "wiki" answer? I have no idea of when they are applied

Comment: @Saeïdryl I added the names of who found what

Comment: Just to get out of the way, number 4 isn't "The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion", is it?

Comment: Nope, it isn't...

Comment: 4 is proving tricky!

Comment: Maybe a little hint? ;)

Comment: No need, @gnovice finally cracked it ;)

Comment: I just saw this! Very cool!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Answer summary** (*thanks to everyone who solved the ones I couldn't*):

1. Chubbier, next not heavy

> Fatter, then light > Faster Than Light (solved by [Saeïdryl](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61839/43477))

2. Goku's friend wheat powder

> Krillin's flour > Killing Floor (solved by [Saeïdryl](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61839/43477))

3. Legolas' dishonesty

> Elf Lie => Half Life (solved by [Paige Meinke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61840/43477))

4. The Iron man's father balloon for showing-off

> The Stan Lee (creator of Iron Man) parade ball(oon) -> The Stanley Parable

5. Hot beverage for Spartacus' fellows

> <strike>Romans' sake -> No Man's Sky</strike>
>  Tea for Thracians -> Team Fortress 1
>  or
>  Tea for Thrace (the nation) -> Team Fortress

6. Higher cute marsupial

> More tall wombat -> Mortal Kombat

7. Mixed great geographic feature

> <strike>Stir ocean -> Star Ocean</strike>
>  Mountain blend -> Mount & Blade (solved by [Milo P](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61850/43477))

8. The 18th Ulysses, the 6th, the 15th and the greek 19th

> Grant (18<sup>th</sup> President) F (6<sup>th</sup> letter of alphabet) O (15<sup>th</sup> letter of alphabet) tau (19<sup>th</sup> letter of Greek alphabet) -> Grand Theft Auto (solved by [Gustavo Gabriel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61842/43477))

9. Assault a person

> Mug a man -> Megaman

10. Evening meal animal flesh in hot water

> Supper meat boil -> Super Meat Boy

Comment: 9 is the "correct" one, 7 is not ;)

Comment: @Keelhaul: Yeah, I thought 7 was a stretch.

Comment: 5 is wrong too :p

Comment: @Keelhaul: Took another stab. Is 5 any better?

Comment: It is! (I'd only use the nation's name rather than the the people's name, the homophony is slightly better that way). Since you found the most answers, maybe you could round them up (only the 4th is missing) and get that green mark ;)

Comment: Well done for number 4! I'd just replace balloon by ball ;)

Answer (score 12):

**Partial answers :**
1. Chubbier, next not heavy

> Fatter, then light > Faster Than Light

2. Goku's friend wheat powder

> Krillin's flour > Killing Floor

9. Assault a person

> Hit a man > Hitman

Comment: I had another idea for 9. Yours works though, can you find the intended one? It's a more "classical" game.

Answer (score 10):

**Partial**

8: The 18th Ulysses, the 6th, the 15th and the greek 19th

> Grand Theft Auto 
>  
>  18th Ulysses was Grant (Grand)
>  The 6th letter is F (Theft)
>  The 15th letter is O and the 19th greek letter is TAU (Auto)

Answer (score 9):

**Partial:**

3. Legolas' dishonesty

> Elf Lie => Half Life

9. Assault a person

> Whack Man => Pac Man

Comment: That's not it (as for number 5, in case you add some more in the meantime)

Comment: rot13 "V jbhyq tb sbe Junpx zna, abg nggnpx zna." Or it really is too far fetched to be a mondegreen

Comment: @PL457 Good idea

Comment: Number 9 is still not wat I had in mind, but this one is quite broad I must admit. Still, your answer for this one is a bit too far fetched^^

Answer (score 8):

7. Mixed great geographic feature

> Mountain Blend -> Mount & Blade (?)

Comment: You got it, well done ;)

Answer (score 1):

7. Mixed great geographic feature

> blend - wonder
>
>  blade runner (1997) ?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you please edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as not to spoil your solution for anyone else who wants to have a go at the puzzle? Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find how to do so, could you enlight me please :)

Comment: Just add `>!` before each of the last two lines, and that should hide them.

Comment: That's not it, sorry (as for the 7, in case you add more)