# Misspelled Movies

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, movies

Continuing in the [Twisted TV Titles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61535/twisted-tv-titles?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [TV Title Mondegreens](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61761/tv-title-mondegreens?noredirect=1&lq=1) vein, here are some Misspelled Movies.

Each title is a homophone of (i.e. sounds the same as<sup>1</sup>) a real movie title, but is spelled and/or punctuated differently. I'll give a description of what the movie could be; you give the misspelled title, along with the real movie title.

<sup><sup>1</sup> In my American English accent, anyway.</sup>

For example:

**Clue:** Thieving guy

**Answer:** Man of Steal (*Man of Steel*)

## The Clues

1. Older female relatives
2. Adam and Eve's son adopts a country
3. It's 3 a.m., cloudy, with no moon
4. *Deinonychus* becomes the new Kris Kringle
5. Get out of here, Jackman!
6. The nanny and the chimney-sweep say "I do"
7. Lazy MD
8. Courageous male deer
9. Spot a cookie
10. They genuflect in glop
11. What Frankenstein writes with
12. Treasure-hunters look for a missing protractor

Comment: I really like #12, it makes me chuckle every time I read it.

Comment: +1 for specifying what accent you have - it definitely makes a difference to a few of them :)

Comment: American English accent but you call a cookie a biscuit?  Hmmmm

Comment: @Kevin ... Or is it that I call a biscuit a cookie? ;)

Comment: I knew you were secretly British and not 'Merican

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With credits to [@Xenocacia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30254/xenocacia), [@PL457](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61964/33080), [@Statman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61966/33080) and [@Ashwin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61969/33080) (please upvote those linked answers) for their assistance on #2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11.

---

1. Older female relatives

> **Antz** (aunts)

2. Adam and Eve's son adopts a country

> [**Citizen Kane**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane) - *with due credit to [Ashwin's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61969/33080).*

3. It's 3 a.m., cloudy, with no moon

> **Dark Knight** (night-time, moonless hence dark) - *thanks to @Xenocacia*

4. Deinonychus becomes the new Kris Kringle

> [**The Santa Clause**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Santa_Clause) (Kris Kringle = Santa Claus, Deinonychus = Greek for *terrible claw*)

5. Get out of here, Jackman!

> **Hugo** (Hugh go) - *thanks to @Statman*

6. The nanny and the chimney-sweep say "I do"

> **Mary Poppins** (Marry pop-in) - *thanks to @PL457*

7. Lazy MD

> **Doctor Dolittle** (do little)

8. Courageous male deer

> **Braveheart** (brave hart)

9. Spot a cookie

> **Sea Biscuit** (see biscuit)

10. They genuflect in glop

> **The Goonies** (goo knees) - *thanks to @Statman*

11. What Frankenstein writes with

> **Monsters Inc.** (monsters' ink) - *thanks to @Statman*

12. Treasure-hunters look for a missing protractor

> **Raiders of the Lost Ark** (arc)

Comment: I added an answer for no. 3, hope that's okay.

Comment: I added no.6 to your collection. So others can see which ones have been answered and which ones are still open.
(nice finds btw)

Comment: Thank you @PL457 , I've also upvoted your answer!

Comment: @Xenocacia - May I suggest that in addition to the answer you added for #3, you create a separate answer for yourself with the same (like PL457's answer)? That'll allow me - and others - to upvote the one that you identified. Otherwise I'll be benefiting off your work, which is unfair.

Comment: @Phylyp: thanks for the thought but it's alright. :)

Comment: #4 makes sense. Kris Kringle = "Santa", Deinonychus = "Claws"

Comment: #4 is correct! Ashwin got the intended answer for #2. Also, check the spelling on #7. ;)

Comment: @DLosc - thank you for those pointers :-) I've made the necessary amendments.

Answer (score 16):

5. Get out of here, Jackman!

> **Hugo** = Hugh go

10. They genuflect in glop

> **The Goonies** = The goo knees (not 100% on this one...)

11 What Frankenstein writes with

> **Monsters Inc** = Monsters' ink

Comment: Nice answers! Well done

Comment: I think your #10 fits perfectly. Nice answers, and thank you for the edit on mine as well.

Answer (score 12):

2. Adam and Eve's son adopts a country

   > Citizen Kane (Cain)

Comment: That one caught my attention as well, but the link between 'adopts a country' and the first part of your title sounds just too fat fetched. (I haven't seen the movie, so that might be why.)

Comment: I think this answer is right. The question isn't perfect but it's difficult to think how it could be improved.

Comment: Very nice, I think you've got this! I agree the 'adops a country' isn't a best fit for the first word, but the homophone is spot on.

Comment: @Chronocidal, you ought to edit your comment so that it doesn't give the answer away.

Comment: Could be idiomatic, In the same way that "adopting an accent" would be to speak in talk as though you came from elsewhere?

Comment: If, as a foreigner, you apply for citizenship in a country, you are -- in a sense -- "adopting" that country as your own, becoming a citizen of it.

Comment: Yes, this is my intended answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

6:The nanny and the chimney-sweep say "I do"

> Marry Poppins (original Mary poppins)

Comment: Nice answer @PL457 !

Answer (score 2):

For #4:

> <s>Is it **Bad Santa?** (Deinonychus = Terrible claw => *Bad* and Kris Kringle = Santa)</s> 
>  Oh wait... Just now saw the homophones part 
>  It must be **Santa Clause** (as Phylyp answered) as (Santa + **Claws**)

Answer (score 2):

Answer for # 11:

> Monsters, Inc. (What Frankenstein writes with - Monster's ink)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This answer was already given a few hours ago - in future, when answering a question, please check that the same answer hasn't already been posted.

Answer (score 1):

2.

> No country for old men. (Adam and Eve's son is the old man. He has no country so he adopts one)