# Twisted Book Titles

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

(Obviously, inspired by [Twisted TV Titles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61535/twisted-tv-titles) and its sequels.)

It's not just TV and movie studios that are facing a lack of original ideas.  In fact, publishing houses have started getting highly derivative submissions.  Each of the book blurbs given below describes a copy of a literary classic with the title changed by just one letter.  Identify each modified title.

(Sorry if this is biased somewhat towards American literature.  Also, I have no drawing skills, so sorry, there won't be any visual clues in this one.)

> 1. In this play set in Renaissance Padua, an Italian nobleman finds his new acquisition has stripped threads.
> 2. A grown man with the mentality of a child imagines himself protecting children playing in a clothing factory from falling into the vats.
> 3. In nineteenth century St. Petersburg, a detective must solve the murder of a pastry chef.
> 4. Follows the exploits of an irreverent young attorney in frontier Missouri.
> 5. A modernist tale of an epic struggle to find something hot to drink.
> 6. Against the backdrop of Napoleon's invasion of Russia, follows the lives of ordinary Russian golfers.
> 7. A family flees the Dust Bowl for California, where they find work as interior decorators.
> 8. In an allegory of the Bolshevik Revolution, anthropomorphic beasts rebel against their cruel HR department.
> 9. Chronicles incredible discounts during the French Revolution.
> 10. In a small Puritan town, an adulteress is sentenced to pick up trash.

Comment: One of these must be *Les Miserables* by Victor Hughes

Comment: @North That one was definitely on my mind, but unfortunately I couldn't find any way to fit it into the format.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful puzzle!  A lot of these made me chuckle :)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Great Puzzle, man! Keep on making more! I'm excited to see more from you :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1:

> The Taming of the Screw (from Shakespeare's "The Taming of the Shrew")

2 (credit goes to [edderiofer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34310/edderiofer), thank you!):

> The Catcher in the Dye (from Salinger's "The Catcher in the Rye")

3:

> Creme and Punishment (from Dostoevsky's "Crime and Punishment")?

4:

> The Adventures of Tom Lawyer (from Twain's "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer")

5:

> The Old Man and the Tea (from Hemingway's "The Old Man and the Sea")?

6 (solved by [QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63578/38170) and [North](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63577/38170), upvote their answers!):

> Par and Peace (from Tolstoy's "War and Peace")

7:

> The Drapes of Wrath (from Steinbeck's "The Grapes of Wrath")

8:

> Animal Firm (from Orwell's "Animal Farm")

9:

> A Sale of Two Cities (from Dickens' "A Tale of Two Cities")

10 (solved first by [QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63578/38170)):

> The Scarlet Litter (from Hawthorne's "The Scarlet Letter")

Comment: #2 is "Catcher in the Dye", from J.D. Salinger's "Catcher In The Rye".

Comment: @edderiofer Why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 13):

6 is

> Par and Peace(war) by Leo Tolstoy(War and Peace from North :D)

Is 10

> *The Scarlet Litter*(letter) by Nathaniel Hawthorne

Answer (score 10):

6 is

> Par (War)and Peace (Thanks @QuantumTwinkie)