# Twisted Authors

Tags: riddle, wordplay, visual

Inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61535/twisted-tv-titles) great puzzle I made one where you change the letter of the authors(whom the clue hints at) name. Have fun!

> 1. Writes about wizards, material-worms, and cuckoo birds, and has a interest for spare-turkeys.
> 2. Writes about pronoun-clowns and presenting musical poetry.
> 3. Writes about the Mississippi, slaves and nature reserves(or playgrounds).
> 4. Writes about flower juice, high temperatures, and water inlets.
> 5. Writes about black birds, ding-dong noises, and onomatopoeia music.
> 6. Writes about grass, songs about himself, and poems about himself, while telling people to STOP.
> 7. Writer who got his PHD taken away. Now he is just regular.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete Answer

1:

> JK Bowling (JK Rowling)

2:

> Stephen Sing (Stephen King)

3:

> Park Twain (Mark Twain)

4:

> Bay Bradbury (Ray Bradbury)

5: (from [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63864/46820/))

> Edgar Allen Pop

6:

> Halt Whitman (Walt Whitman)

7: (from [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63864/46820/) and me)

> Mr. Seuss

8: (from [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63864/46820/))

> Jane Austin

Comment: I had something different in mind for the first one but the rest are right.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie How about now?

Comment: Yes good job! All are solved good job @Riley too

Comment: These are a fun type of puzzle. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer

5.

> Edgar Allen Pop

7.

> Mr. Seuss? @Aces

8.

> Jane Austin

Comment: Could #7 possibly be rot13(e frhff)?

Comment: @Aces Good idea, that's probably right